# packing ellipses inside a circular domain

Tags: image, matlab, plot

I wrote a code to pack random ellipses inside a circular domain.
My code is working fine. But the problem is that the logic to check overlap is very crude, it checks the center distance between two ellipses.
By this logic the code is taking too much time for higher volume fractions.
How can I check the distance between points on the ellipse to check overlap i think that will be more efficient, this logic will not create a bounding circle around the ellipses. We can also move the ellipses slightly till the overlap is removed if it is taking too much time (but this will lead to clustering). Is it possible to create a bounding ellipse
Please help me by modifying my code. I wanted to go upto 55% Volume fraction.
I am attaching my code.

```
close all;
clear;
clc;
format short;

%% Input form user

prompt={'Volume fraction of particles: ',...
    'Clad ID: ', 'Particle Semi-Major Axis: ', ...
    'Particle Semi-Minor Axis: ','Image Size: ' };
name = 'Dispersion Fuel Generator';
numlines=1; defaultanswer={'0.2', '1024', '30','15', '2048'};
options.Resize='on'; options.WindowStyle='normal'; options.Interpreter='tex';
answer=inputdlg(prompt,name,numlines,defaultanswer,options);

Vf = str2double(answer(1));
bigR = str2double(answer(2));                % Radius of circular domain
semiMajorAxis = str2double(answer(3));       % Semi-major axis of ellipses
semiMinorAxis = str2double(answer(4));       % Semi-minor axis of ellipses
w = str2double(answer(5));                   % Image size
wantN  = round((1*Vf*bigR^2)/(semiMajorAxis*semiMinorAxis));  

%% Initialization

N             = 0;
centers       = zeros(wantN, 2);  % List of centers
angles        = rand(wantN, 1) * pi; % Random angle for each ellipse
iter          = 0;

%% Checking for overlap

h = waitbar(0, 'Please wait...', 'Name', 'Micro structure generator');
while N < wantN
    c = rand(1, 2) * w;
    reject = any(vecnorm(c - centers(1:N, :), 2, 2) < 2.1*semiMajorAxis) | ...  %% controlling neighbouring particle distance
        (vecnorm(c - [w/2 w/2], 2, 2) >= bigR - semiMajorAxis - semiMinorAxis);  %% controlling the boundary
    if ~reject
        N = N + 1;
        centers(N, :) = c;
    end 
    
    % Update progress dialog box
    waitbar(N / wantN, h, sprintf('Progress: %d/%d', N, wantN));
end
close(h); % Close progress dialog box


%% Visualization

img = ones(w, w, 3);
img = drawEllipse(img, [w/2, w/2], bigR, bigR, [0,0,0]); % Circular domain
for i = 1:wantN   % Ellipses
    img = drawEllipse(img, centers(i, :), semiMajorAxis, semiMinorAxis, [1,1,1], angles(i));
end
image(img);
axis off
title("Dispersion Fuel")
axis equal;
centers = centers - w/2;
angles = angles*180/pi ;

Ellipse_Data = [centers angles];



function img = drawEllipse(img, C, a, b, Color, angle)
    if nargin < 6
        angle = 0;
    end
    s    = size(img);
    [X, Y] = meshgrid(1:s(1), 1:s(2));
    X = X - C(1);
    Y = Y - C(2);
    cosAngle = cos(angle);
    sinAngle = sin(angle);
    mask = ((X*cosAngle + Y*sinAngle).^2/a^2 + (X*sinAngle - Y*cosAngle).^2/b^2) <= 1;
    img  = reshape(img, [], 3);
    img(mask, 1) = Color(1);
    img(mask, 2) = Color(2);
    img(mask, 3) = Color(3);
    img = reshape(img, s);
end
```

By this logic the code is taking too much time for higher volume fractions.
How can I check the distance between points on the ellipse to check overlap i think that will be more efficient, this logic will not create a bounding circle around the ellipses. We can also move the ellipses slightly till the overlap is removed if it is taking too much time (but this will lead to clustering). Is it possible to create a bounding ellipse
Please help me by modifying my code. I wanted to go upto 55% Volume fraction.

Comment: This is an optimisation problem still being actively researched. You could get some inspiration from this paper: [General Ellipse Packings in an Optimized Circle](https://optimization-online.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/5293.pdf), or from this answer: [Fill area with random circles having different diameters](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/405186-fill-area-with-random-circles-having-different-diameters#comment_578048), by adjusting the equations for elipses instead of `minR` and `maxR`. There won't be a trivial solution in any case.

Comment: Also, with your current major/minor axis ellipse configuration, each actual ellipse only occupies 50% of the surface of its containing circle, which means the rejection method (which uses a full circle) is wasting 50% of the available area ... with so much waste you can never reach your 55% volume fraction. You have to use a tighter overlap detection method if you want to increase the packing efficiency.

Comment: So, why processing tag?